# Should I store static files (photos) local or in the cloud?

Tags: python, django, cloud-hosting, photo-gallery

I have this small app in Django, hosted on cheap linode. We want to add photo-sharing functionality so I am wondering should I put all user uploaded static photo files locally on linode serwer or it is better to use Amazon S3 or similar cloud soulution ?

What are pros and cons of both solutions ?

Comment: Better is to serve Django app with Nginx and serve pics by it too. On my taste of course

Comment: why ? pros and cons ?

Answer (score 2):

### Pros:

1. You don't have to pay extra for your S3 servers after it crosses the 20GB limit.

### Cons

1. Your server will slow down as it will not be able to take the load after certain limit.
2. Performance of the server will go down, in worst case your servers may crash.
3. Your node will also have limit on the disk space, which you cannot exceed but S3 or any other service will be able to do it seamlessly.